# Download a javascript generated image

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2

I am trying to download a javascript generated image. Basically I am opening a link/webpage using `urllib2.build_opener()` and as a result the client will do some GETs and POSTs. Among these links a javascript generated image is created that looks like this:

```
<img id="image" src="/index.php?x=img&amp;y=code" onclick="this.src='/index.php?x=img&amp;y=code&amp;'+Math.random();">
```

(notice the Math.random() function in the end) that produces this link on the client side:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?x=img&y=code&0.7487168334519124
```

which will be shown as an image on web browsers. I am asking myself how can I download that image? I think I somehow have to tell python to download the result of this "GET" but how can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how you can download it yourself from the image element in your browser? (Right-click on the image and download) or instead how to offer a link to the user that allows them to download it?

Comment: i am trying to do the image download yes, but in python (command line) which I dont know how to do. When I load the page, the image is created right at the GET request, so I need to download the response. I cant do a simple `urllib.urlretrieve(link, "1.jpg")` because its a captcha. The captcha should be loaded only once.

Comment: Is that tag always the same image?

Comment: what do you mean? Its always a different image (server-side generated).

Comment: Can you share the url? Also did you just try using `random.random()` to generate a random decimal?